# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: apache, wamp, cs-cart

I understand this error is fairly common, but I've come to a bit of a dead end in terms of debugging the issue. I'm running windows 8.1 with WAMP. I have multiple websites running from the WAMP configuration, most of them being Drupal sites and a couple being CS-Cart sites. The one I'm having an issue with is the CS-Cart site.

I've setup my hosts/vhosts file in exactly the same way I've set up all of my existing sites. However when I go to the browser and try and view the site, I get a 'Service unavailable' message. In my console it turns out it's a `'503 Service Temporarily Unavailable'`. I've checked the database settings and I have an .htaccess file.

Here is an example of my hosts file config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@email.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/website-location"
    ServerName local.website.co.uk
    ErrorLog "logs/local.website.co.uk-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/local.website.co.uk-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

127.0.0.1     local.website.co.uk
```

I've checked the error logs and it's not printing anything at all. The only thing I can see are the HTTP requests in the access file. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the `apache` error log for errors?

Comment: This may help - http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,115474

Comment: The Icon is green, all the other sites are still running. It's just this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, So I managed to sort out the issue. Turns out the issue was in the Database. There is a table called `'CSCART_COMPANIES'`, the domain was pointing to the staging site as opposed to the local site.

Hopefully this helps others out in the future.

Comment: Not sure if older installs had this, but there is another `company_website` row found in `cscart_settings_objects` table that should prob be changed as well if its not already. Also, there is a license key there too that is domain based if you are changing domain names.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your config.local.php file which is located on the root directory.

Within you need to change  $config['http_host']

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem - when clicked on category I was presented with Service Unavailable error message.
I sorted it by going into Products/ Filters and disabled all filters.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the "Service Unavailable" in CS-Cart admin and catalog side this morning. The first thing to check is the source of the page. It should say what kind of error/exception is thrown as a comment near the bottom.

In this case, it was 503 error. The culprit? Cache backend crashed. Redis had ran out of mem due to a big nightly backup colliding with an SEO speeder trying to gen cache for entire site.

If your redis has not recovered, you can start it with `# service redis start` (or `restart`).

To see some details of what happened, you can run `# grep -i redis /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log` and look for strings like "cant connect to redis server" or `# grep redis /var/log/messages` may return a line saying "OOM killed process 123 (redis-server)" where 123 is the PID of redis.

Answer (score 0):

**In addition to the @JDavies answer,**

Even CSCART docs page doesn't tell you the correct answer.

Here is the one if someone gets stuck in this error,

Goto your admin panel Settings -> General and find a checkbox with label 'Close storefront:', uncheck it and you are good.

I am using 4.3.1 version, probably this will cover all versions.

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely caused by your site having met its maximum concurrent connection (simultaneous visitors) limit.